# Kafka - Confluent Cloud - what is the status and limitations?

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform

Did anyone used Confluent Cloud in Production?

What is the status of it?

I heard that it allows replication without renaming the topic and offsets to be consistent in replicas.

Is that true?

Also - can NPI data be used for it?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about product availability and high-level product features/comparison.

Comment: I'd suggest to ask this product question in the Confluent Slack community (https://slackpass.io/confluentcommunity) or in the Confluent Platform google group/mailing list (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/confluent-platform/).